# random variable of variable

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics

Most computer languages have functions that can be used to generate random numbers. In Excel, the RAND function can be used to generate random numbers between $0$ and $1$. If we let $x$ denote a random number generated, then $x$ is a continuous random variable with the following probability density function. 
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{$0\leq x\leq 1$ } \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$

$a)$  What is the probability of generating a random number with a value less than or equal to $0.30$?

$b)$  What is the probability of generating a random number with value greater than $0.60$?

$c)$  Find the mean of the random variable $x$.

Comment: What have you tried? What are your thoughts on this problem? What is the context of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$\begin{align}
P(X\leq 0.30)&=\int_0^{0.30} f(x) dx\\
&=\int_0^{0.30} 1 dx\\
&=0.30
\end{align}$

Similarly calculate the second one.

To find out third, use

$\begin{align}E(X)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x) dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}x\cdot 1 dx
\end{align} $

Comment: for the second it answer 0.3/1 = 0.3 = 30%

Comment: for the thired who i can answer

Comment: @Abeer No. For the second part you should get  $0.40$ as probability. Please check your integral again. Something must be wrong.

Comment: @Abeer Have you computed the third part? Can you tell me your answer?